# Someway to select rows to columns - SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I want to know if exist some way to select the table bellow...

```
ID | DOCNo | Date

1  | 20    | 12-DEC-12
2  | 21    | 02-NOV-12
3  | 20    | 18-JAN-13
4  | 20    | 10-APR-13
5  | 22    | 12-DEC-12
```

to do something like this in SQL SERVER 2008:

```
DOCNo | ID1 | Date1     | ID2  | Date2     | ID3  | Date3 

20    |  1  | 12-DEC-12 |  3   | 18-JAN-13 |  4   | 10-APR-13  
21    |  2  | 02-NOV-12 | NULL |   NULL    | NULL |   NULL    
22    |  5  | 12-DEC-12 | NULL |   NULL    | NULL |   NULL
```

*The DOCNo will never have more than 3 records in table

I am using SQL Server 2008.

Thanks!!!

Comment: Are there a finite number of IDn in the `SELECT` table. Meaning ID1, ID2, ID3 is that where it stops or is it infinate. Can you have 7, 10, 15...

Comment: Actually I just saw that: `The DOCNo will never have more than 3 records in table`.... Does it have to be one Query or can it be a stored procedure.... I can think of a way in a procedure using temp tables.

Comment: Hi logixologist, Thanks for your reply... Do you think is possible to be one query? It´s the best choice for me...

Answer (score 0):

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/a3da0/1)

**MS SQL Server 2008 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE Table1
    ([ID] int, [DOCNo] int, [Date] varchar(9))
;

INSERT INTO Table1
    ([ID], [DOCNo], [Date])
VALUES
    (1, 20, '12-DEC-12'),
    (2, 21, '02-NOV-12'),
    (3, 20, '18-JAN-13'),
    (4, 20, '10-APR-13'),
    (5, 22, '12-DEC-12'),
    (6, 23, '21-JAN-13'),
    (7, 23, '24-FEB-13')
;
```

**Query 1**:

```
SELECT r1.DOCNo, 
       r1.ID as ID1, r1.Date as Date1,
       r2.ID as ID2, r2.Date as Date2,
       r3.ID as ID3, r3.Date as Date3
FROM Table1 r1
LEFT OUTER JOIN Table1 r2 ON r1.DOCNo = r2.DOCNo AND r1.ID < r2.ID
LEFT OUTER JOIN Table1 r3 ON r1.DOCNo = r3.DOCNo AND r1.ID < r3.ID 
                                                 AND r2.ID < r3.ID
WHERE r1.ID = (SELECT min(ID) 
                 FROM Table1 
                WHERE DOCNo = r1.DOCNo 
                GROUP BY DOCNo)
AND (CASE WHEN (SELECT count(*) 
                  FROM Table1 
                 WHERE DOCNo = r1.DOCNo 
                 GROUP BY DOCNo) = 2 THEN r2.ID
          WHEN (SELECT count(*) 
                  FROM Table1 
                 WHERE DOCNo = r1.DOCNo 
                 GROUP BY DOCNo) = 3 THEN r3.ID ELSE 1 END) IS NOT NULL
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/a3da0/1/0)**:

```
| DOCNO | ID1 |     DATE1 |    ID2 |     DATE2 |    ID3 |     DATE3 |
|-------|-----|-----------|--------|-----------|--------|-----------|
|    20 |   1 | 12-DEC-12 |      3 | 18-JAN-13 |      4 | 10-APR-13 |
|    21 |   2 | 02-NOV-12 | (null) |    (null) | (null) |    (null) |
|    22 |   5 | 12-DEC-12 | (null) |    (null) | (null) |    (null) |
|    23 |   6 | 21-JAN-13 |      7 | 24-FEB-13 | (null) |    (null) |
```

Answer (score 0):

An easy way to get the final result would be to use `row_number()` to generate a sequence for each `docno` and then apply an aggregate function with a CASE expression:

```
select docno,
  max(case when seq = 1 then id end) id1,
  max(case when seq = 1 then date end) date1,
  max(case when seq = 2 then id end) id2,
  max(case when seq = 2 then date end) date2,
  max(case when seq = 3 then id end) id3,
  max(case when seq = 3 then date end) date3
from
(
  select id, docno, date,
    row_number() over(partition by docno order by date) seq
  from yourtable
) d
group by docno;
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/c2143/1)